# Running a SOAP API through WCF while running a RESTFul service in parallel

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest, soap

I have a handful of **SOAP .svc** endpoints that are hit currently, but I need to add RESTful endpoints to my project while still maintaining the old endpoints.

Everything is currently hosted through IIS, just as a simple Website in an app pool etc.

I was looking into using **ASP.NET MVC** to implement the RESTful API, but I have no idea how I'm going to host this side-by-side with the **SOAP/WCF** interfaces. I've read that this may be possible with Service Routing?

An example of how I want things to look :

> website.com/base.svc (SOAP envelope/method "Activate" with parameters)

> POST website.com/activation/deviceNumber/123 (POSTing other parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may want to host your REST service endpoints using WCF.

You basically need to:

.1. expand the "web method" attributes to include:

```
[OperationContract]  
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "website.com/activation/deviceNumber/{id}")]
```

.2. add another service endpoint using the webHttpBinding:

```
<service name="BaseService">
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" ...
    <endpoint address="xml" binding="webHttpBinding" ...
```

The following link provides a good overview:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services

Comment: Is this as "clean" as building the endpoints through something like ASP.NET?

Comment: If I understand your scenario correctly, to host both SOAP and REST versions of the same service, then combining the endpoints in the same service seems like a good, "clean" solution.

Comment: I guess partially what i'm asking is if this would be considered a good, and true RESTful interface.

Looking at this, is this approach "Level 2"?

http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html

Comment: I think, the short answer is yes for "Level 2" on the RMM model. The following link provides comprehensive details:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/611238/Web-API-and-Windows-Azure-Part-1-History-a-bit-abo

Comment: I'm going to have to look into this a lot more to see if it's the solution i'm looking for. I'm still weary of the translation within WCF, but I think that's just my lack of confidence with REST right now. I'm not even sure where I would be putting the OperationContract, since one RESTful endpoint will essentially be what is currently multiple SOAP endpoints, I don't know the structure of the files or how to get WCF to know what to look at. Right now we use ServiceHost definitions within an SVC to point at our Services (C#). Thank you though, i'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 1):

The below answer is pretty boiler-plate stuff so it will hopefully be helpful for others consulting it, i.e. I am not trying to insult anyone's intelligence.

### Mildly Unsubstantiated Opinion:

There are a number of resources you will want to consult on how to do this (there's also a lot of crap and only minimally helpful resources on this, too). Unfortunately, a lot of the bad information is found on CodeProject - that's only my opinion, though.

I would start by consulting some of the resources on C-Sharp Corner, particularly [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/how-to-enable-rest-and-soap-both-on-the-same-wcf-service/) by Dhananjay Kumar. There's a bit of a learning curve (and some things are left to inference), but it is the *best* resource that I have found. However, regardless of the resource you consult, the other post is right that this is all best done through Windows Communication Foundation (WCF; or, "dub-C-F").

I am terrible at `.config` files (one of the major complaints about the .Net Framework pre-4.5 is the large size of `.config` files; Google "avoiding `.config` files" and you'll see a lot of 'stuff'). Really, after delving into them for a few hours, they begin to make sense. But, learning how to use `.config` files does require a bit of attention. With the .Net 4.5 Framework, however, a lot of that changed: from my reading, Microsoft set out to eliminate the burdensome `.config` files as much as possible. Everything you can do from a `.config` file, you can do from code (and approaching it from code can sometimes offer a better understanding of `.config`s).

### My Own Problem:

I needed to create a `Windows Service` that exposed both SOAP and RESTful endpoints *without using a* `.config` *file* (my office currently discourages there use for the same reason - time - mentioned above).

### A no-.config Solution:

I'll provide some of the code, here, that I used for my service and some explanation. Some will be psuedo-code. I wrote this in the .Net 3.5 Framework. 4.5 offers much greater flexibility and precision with your code when isolating configurations for your service.

#### Separating Out Your Interfaces

Simple enough, right? Design one interface for SOAP endpoints (`ISOAP`) and another for RESTful endpoints (`IREST`). Implement and define (i.e. give body to the function signatures) in one class, let's call it `DualService`. The separating out of the interfaces really does nothing but help us logically (and allows you to put them in place, separately, if needed, later; why waste good time and code by sacrificing re-usability?).

#### Interface Defintions

*Note: all the code, here, is written in the rather "verbose" VB.NET language. Unfortunately, SO doesn't particularly have a good time with VB Comments (or Microsoft's old-school `REM` keyword), so I use the `//` comment syntax. There are better resources on the internet for C# stuff (hence my referencing C-Sharp Corner)*

**SOAP**

```
// Decorate each interface with the Service Contract decoration:
<ServiceContract()> _
Public Interface ISOAP 

// For SOAP, each exposed operation gets the Operation Contract definition:
<OperationContract()> _
Function DoSomethingSOAP() As Boolean

End Interface
```

BOOM! We've got our SOAP service interface. SOAP *only* uses XML for serialization - which improves it's interoperability according to MSDN. Unlike REST, SOAP can be configured to use a variety of protocols for data exchange (we'll just use `HTTP`).

**REST**

REST - in interface design - really isn't that different from SOAP. The real difference relies in two things: (1) how the data is serialized; and (2) specifying how the endpoint - or, in "true" REST-speak, "resource - is accessed (both of which - and the 'oh such much more' - I am sure you are already familiar with; if not, here's a moderately helpful [resource](http://spf13.com/post/soap-vs-rest)

```
// Again, we decorate with the Service Contract decoration:
<ServiceContract()> _ 
Public Interface IREST

// Here is/are the above mentioned difference(s)
// Some resources will tell you REST doesn't have a default communication
// format. That's non-sense. In .NET it's XML (hence, it ain't specified, below):
<OperationContract()> _
<WebInvoke(UriTemplate:="/POSTSOMETHING", Method:="POST")> _
Function DoSomethingREST(ByVal anObject As aCustomTypePerhaps) As Boolean
```

#### Time To Implement

Really, I'm trying to keep this brief as the meat of my code comes later.

```
Public Class DualService
Implements ISOAP, IRest

Function DoSomethingSOAP() As Boolean Implements ISOAP.DoSomethingSOAP
    Dim Result As Boolean = True
        // Figure out what to do with errors
    Return Result
End Function

Function DoSomethingREST(ByVal anObject As CustomTypePerhaps) As Boolean Implements IREST.DoSomethingREST
    Dim Result As Boolean = True
        // Don't need to do anything with errors; HTTP errors will do that for you
    Return Result
End Result
```

#### What Now?: Expose the Service

*Note: Again, this is all done from code. Some of it may end up being a bit pseudo-y. Also, please, for the sake of all that is good, better organize that which you are about the encounter, below*

As mentioned above, below is the meaty bit. Not to worry. It's meaty because I wanted to organize it more logically in hopes that the calls and configuration would make more sense. Again, this can all be configured from a `.config` file and is much easier to do with the 4.5 Framework.

```
// Instantiate an accessible ServiceHost-type variable. Notice, the GetType() call
// Each subsequent call sets the service up for SOAP and REST (WebHTTPBinding), and
// adds various behaviors to the service, including metadata behavior:
Private Sub ConfigureServiceHost(ByVal aHostName As String, ByVal aPort As Integer)
    Dim URL As String = String.Format("http://{0}:{1}/Service/", aHostName, aPort)
    _ServiceHost = New ServiceHost(GetType(DualService), New Uri(URL))

    AddWebHTTPBinding()
    AddSOAPBinding()
    AddServiceBehavior()

End Sub

// Here, again, notice the call to GetType() - another reason for separating our interfaces
Private Sub AddWebHTTPBinding()
    Dim _WebHTTPBinding As New WebHttpBinding
    Dim EndPoint As ServiceEndpoint
    Dim _WebHTTPBehavior As New WebHttpBehavior

    _WebHTTPBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue
    _WebHTTPBinding.SendTimeout = New System.TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)
    _WebHTTPBinding.ReceiveTimeout = New System.TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)

    // If these calls are foreign, look them up in MSDN. Here, you are adding an EndPoint
    // to _ServiceHost of type IREST, with the specified behavior, at location "/WebService"
    EndPoint = _ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(IREST), _WebHTTPBinding, "WebService")
    EndPoint.Behaviors.Add(_WebHTTPBehavior)

End Sub

// Let's set up SOAP:
Private Sub AddSOAPBinding()
    Dim _BasicHTTPBinding As New BasicHttpBinding
    Dim EndPoint As ServiceEndpoint

    // See the comment for the similar call in the AddWebHttpBinding call:
    EndPoint = _ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(ISOAP), _BasicHTTPBinding, "SOAP")

End Sub

// Let's get our metadata on, y'all!
// This just enables people developing clients to be able to hit our service, looking for WSDL
// and HELP information. 
Private Sub AddServiceBehavior()
    Dim _ServiceMetadataBehavior As ServiceMetadataBehavior = New ServiceMetadataBehavior

    _ServiceMetadataBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = True
    _ServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(_ServiceMetadataBehavior)

End Sub
```

### Wrap Up

So, what's really 'going on' here is that you are instantiating a `ServiceHost` which has the Service-type of `DualService` - a service that implements *both* calls to a RESTful and SOAP-based interface. However, the caveat is - as you can see in the code - that when adding endpoints, you must specify which interface contains which exposed calls - for `WebHttpBinding` we've got our `IREST` `Interface` and for everything SOAP, we've got `ISOAP`.

I don't know what the error handling would be like; but, theoretically, you can have one `Function` in .NET `Implements` two `Interface`'s signatures (here, I'm speaking hypothetically about `DualService`). What this would do, I am unsure - as I didn't pursue it beyond noticing that I could do it. But, if it really works, you could reduce your code a bit. Again, the "problem" would be `FaultExceptions` thrown by the SOAP Service.

Here's the code (in this case, both interface signatures would need to be identical - use your imagination):

```
Function DoSomething(ByVal aBluh As TDog) As Boolean Implements IREST.DoSomethingREST, ISOAP.DoSomethingSOAP
```

This is a pretty code-heavy way of exposing a service. Essentially, the accepted answer does much of what is found below in a `.config` file (I believe `.config` files are very elegant).

Also, as a final note, for `IREST`, I exposed a POST (`WebInvoke`) call as those are the trickier calls that no one seems to like using as examples. That's the only reason I changed the signature a bit in the example.

Comment: Also, I don't know how new you are to Web Services. But, much like SOAP, you can't hit other-than-GET calls from a browser with REST. A great resource for hitting those calls is Fiddler (which requires a bit of knowledge about HTTP packets).